# Spring 3 MVC multi page form with session attributes, cannot go back

Tags: forms, session, button, spring-mvc, back

I wrote relatively simple web app in Spring MVC. I have following multipage forms:

1. Fill in
2. Check preview and eventually go back to 1. by form button or back button in your browser
3. Confirm

I used annotation `@SessionAttributes` and everything goes well, besides of going back to edit form after preview.

Then I have an information that document has expired in browser and I have to renew my POST request hence creating new objects. I resolved this problem by creating another method which loads view with form and loads there information from session, but still I can't use 'back button' in my browser. I would like to avoid javascript in this problem. Any ideas?

EDIT: I can see when session is active header is always set to 'no cache no store', maybe there is a way to configure Spring Session to enable cache and store? I searched but didn't find anything helpful.